# Rails STI with devise and rolify error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, runtime-error, sti, rolify

I'm developing a Rails 3.2.13 app using Devise and Rolify, and I need to have 3 user types as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  ...
end

class UserTypeOne < User
  ....
end

class UserTypeTwo < User
  ....
end

class UserTypeThree < User
  ....
end
```

When I try to seed my db, que creation of users works ok, but it gives an error when trying to add a role to any of them:

```
user = UserTypeOne.find_or_create_by_email :name => 'User one', :email => 'userone@test.com', :password => 'userone', :password_confirmation => 'userone'
user.confirm!
user.add_role :admin

rake aborted!
undefined method `find_or_create_by' for nil:NilClass
```

But the user is inserted correctly... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jacob I didn't. I'm finally removing Rolify from this project because I can implement the basic roles functionality I need with the STI it self. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
self.adapter = User.adapter
```

To each of the inherited classes.

Example:

```
class UserTypeOne < User
  self.adapter = User.adapter 
  ....
end
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When using STI in ActiveRecord, Rolify only knows to look in the current class
and not the parents.

Here is the issue:
https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/138

Ethans answer above should work but [Here](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/FAQ#does-rolify-support-sti-) is the answer in the Rolify FAQ.

Personally, I don't like either of those solutions. 
Perhaps Rolify could pass the adapter along when the class is inherited. Something like:

```
def self.inherited(klass)
    klass.adapter = self.adapter
    super # EDIT: added super call to prevent ActiveRecord error (NoMethodError: undefined method `synchronize' for nil:NilClass)
end
```